# Why airflow add dag to queue immediately after he finish?

Tags: python, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have dag:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 4, 1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    max_active_runs=1
)
```

I want to airflow run this dag each day, but he runs immediately again when dag finished. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dag is trying to catchup to the current time. You can set the catchup property to False in the dag and then you can give any start_date.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html#catchup

Answer (score 1):

I changed start_date to current date and it works:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 27, 13),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}
```